# StackNavigator inside TabNavigator inside DrawerNavigator - How to display header?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

This is my app structure. I have implemented using react-navigation for `drawer, Tab and Stack Navigation`. How to handle header?

**Root Stack:**

```
const PrimaryNav = StackNavigator({
   drawerStack: { screen: DrawerNavigation }
}
```

**DrawerNavigation:**

```
const DrawerStack = DrawerNavigator({
  'screen 1': {screen: Screen1TabNav},
  'screen 2': {screen: Screen2TabNav},
},{
  gesturesEnabled: false,
  contentComponent: DrawerContainer
})

const DrawerNavigation = StackNavigator({
  DrawerStack: { screen: DrawerStack }
  },{
    headerMode: 'float',
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    headerStyle: {backgroundColor: colors.border_color, height: 60},
    title: 'screenName',
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    gesturesEnabled: false,            // not to go login screen back
    headerLeft: drawerButton(navigation)
  })
})
```

**Tab Navigator:**

```
const Screen1TabNav = TabNavigator({
  Tab1: {
    screen: StackNav, 
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon:  
    }
  },
  Tab2: {
    screen: StackNav, 
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon:
    }
  },{
    navigationOptions: {
    header: (
      <View style={[{backgroundColor: '#5E565A', height: 60}]}>
           ...
      </View>
    )
    }
  }
```

**Stack Navigator:**

```
const StackNav = StackNavigator({
  Main: {
    screen: Addresssearch,
  },
  Detail: {
    screen: DetailScreen,
    navigationOptions: (props) => ({
        title: "Detail",
    })
  }
  },
  { headerMode: 'none'} // Removed Header from this Stack Navigation
)
```

My doubt is, how to handle header.

At home screen,

Whenever I change **TabNavigator**, `header title` has to change. In some Tab, View itself has to change.

Same thing, Whenever I change **drawer Navigator** `header title` has to change.

How to handle reusable custom header for **stack Navigator**?

Comment: Do you want to display header on drawernavigator?

Comment: @Shakti I want to manage the header changes according to the Tab selection and drawer selection.

Comment: sounds weird to me to use a tab navigator and a drawer at the same time. anyways, the code is too long to give simple answers, I'd need a runnable example to help.